# Get all text in a tag unless it is in another tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse some HTML with BeautifulSoup, and I'd like to get all the text (recursively) in a tag, but I want to ignore all text that appears within a `small` tag.  For example, this HTML:

```
<li>
  <a href="/path">
    Final
  </a>
  definition.
  <small>
    Fun fact.
  </small>
</li>
```

should give the text `Final definition.`  Note that this is a minimal example.  In the real HTML, there are many other tags involved, so `small` should be excluded rather than `a` being included.

The `text` attribute of the tag is close to what I want, but it would include `Fun fact.` I could concatenate the text of all children except the `small` tags, but that would leave out `definition.` I couldn't find a method like `get_text_until` (the `small` tag is always at the end), so what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_all` to find all the `<small>` tags, clear them, then use `get_text()`:

```
>>> soup

<li>
<a href="/path">
    Final
  </a>
  definition.
  <small>
    Fun fact.
  </small>
</li>

>>> for el in soup.find_all("small"):
...     el.clear()
...
>>> soup

<li>
<a href="/path">
    Final
  </a>
  definition.
  <small></small>
</li>

>>> soup.get_text()
'\n\n\n    Final\n  \n  definition.\n  \n\n'
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `clear` method.  There's only one `small` tag in my text, and I already have it as a variable at the time, so this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this using recursive method state that you don't want to recurse into child tags:
Like

```
soup.li.find(text=True, recursive=False)
```

So you can do this like

```
' '.join(li.find(text=True, recursive=False) for li in soup.findAll('li', 'a'))
```

Comment: I think you meant `soup.findAll(['li', 'a'])`, and that doesn't give me all the text.  All it gives is `Final`, but no `definition.`  Also, I'd like this to be a little more portable than that.  There might be more than just `a` tags inside of the `li` tag.  It should include all tags except `small`.

Comment: Sorry, I understand now, You can do this

Comment: `''.join(text for text in li.find_all(text=True) if text.parent.name != "small")`